# Are there any Sino-Tibetan languages that don't have an isolating morphology?

Tags: morphology, sino-tibetan

All the Sino-Tibetan languages I can think of are isolating. Are there any with a fusional or agglutinative morphology? If so, can you show some examples?

Comment: Can we have a link to a site that explains linguistic terms?

Comment: Hi thei, one of the best places is Wikipedia - it's concise but in-depth and relatively accurate!

Comment: Old Chinese is thought to have had inflections, which were later lost.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Aren't the Tibeto-Burman languages (under Sino-Tibetan) considered [agglutinative](http://www.infoplease.com/ce6/society/A0861104.html)?

> The Tibeto-Burman languages include Tibetan, Burmese, and a number of
>   other tongues, among which are the Bodo, Garo, and Lushai of Assam,
>   the Kachin of Myanmar (Burma), and perhaps also the languages of the
>   Chins and Nagas of Myanmar, the Karen tongues of Myanmar and Thailand,
>   and the Lolo of SW China. Tibeto-Burman languages are likely to be
>   tonal and have anywhere from two to six tones. ***They are less
>   monosyllabic and isolating than the languages of the other
>   Sino-Tibetan families. In fact, they tend to be somewhat agglutinative
>   and exhibit some degree of inflection.*** In an agglutinative language,
>   different linguistic elements, each of which exists separately and has
>   a fixed meaning, are joined to form one word. Affixes added to an
>   unchanged root serve as the usual method of indicating inflection in
>   the Tibeto-Burman tongues.

Answer (score 16):

The Sino-Tibetan language family is rather large with around 450 languages (making it slightly larger than the Indo-European family by some counts). Within the Sino-Tibetan family you have the Tibeto-Burman family, which has around 430 members, making it a disproportionately large sub-family. The other 15 or so languages are in the Chinese family, which are those heavily isolating languages, but the  majority of the Tibeto-Burman group are relatively agglutinating. Many of the Central Bodic languages I work on have at least affixed tense, aspect, negation, plurals and case marking.

Answer (score 3):

Check Qiangic for example - a group of fairly agglutinative languages. There are many other non-isolating ST groups; moreover, the Proto-Sino-Tibetan itself is considered agglutinative by many scholars.